# article post not updating in codeigniter blog

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I build a cms with codeigniter for blog. But when i want edit a article post and want to save it, it create new one post not update old post which i edited.

Please help me.

My Article Edit crontroller:

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
    {
        // Fetch a article or set a new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['article']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'article could not be found';
        }
        else {
            $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get_new();
        }


        // categories for dropdown
        $this->data['all_categories'] = $this->article_m->join();



        // Set up the form
        $rules = $this->article_m->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        // Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $data = $this->article_m->array_from_post(array(
                'title', 
                'extra_title', 
                'slug',
                'image',
                'category_id', 
                'body', 
                'pubdate'
            ));
            $this->article_m->save($data, $id);
            redirect('admin/article');
        }

        // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/article/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

My Models:

```
public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}

public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL){

    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;

        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}
public function get_new ()
{
    $article = new stdClass();
    $article->title = '';
    $article->extra_title = '';
    $article->slug = '';
    $article->image = '';
    $article->category_id = '';
    $article->body = '';
    $article->pubdate = date('Y-m-d');
    return $article;
}

public function join()
{
    $this->db->select('name,categories.id as category_id');
    $this->db->from($this->_table_name);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = category_id','right');
    $Q = $this->db->get();
 if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
   foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
     $data[$row['category_id']] = $row['name'];
   }
   }
   $Q->free_result();  
   return $data;
}
```

My View:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/article/edit'); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Publication date</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('pubdate', set_value('pubdate', $article->pubdate), 'class="datepicker"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td><?php

        $js = 'id="category_id" onChange="some function();"';


         echo form_dropdown('category_id', $all_categories, set_value('category_id', $article->category_id), $js); ?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', $article->title)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Extra Title (Optional)</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('extra_title', set_value('extra_title', $article->extra_title)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Slug</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('slug', set_value('slug', $article->slug)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Upload Image</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-append">
            <?php echo form_input('image', set_value('image', $article->image),'id="fieldID"'); ?>
                <a href="http://localhost/cms/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&field_id=fieldID" class="btn iframe-btn" type="button">Select</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Body</td>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea('body', set_value('body', $article->body), 'class="tinymce"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the id to the controller. In your view you are telling the form to submit to
article/edit but not the id.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/article/edit/'.$article->id); ?>
...
```

You'll probably get some warnings if $article is not set, so you may want to put in some checks for when you're adding a new item.